# how do periodically schedule notifications in background when app is in the terminated state in Flutter?

Tags: flutter-dependencies, flutter-workmanager

The work manager package work fine and I have checked the time of each notification which is correct but still the notification show on wrong time. I also use short time for the purose of testing it's work fine. Also the work manager not working in some android phone. Is there any restriction of OS on background workmanager.